# How To Merge Two Dictionaries With Common and Different Keys in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, merge, key

I am trying to make a function that will take two dictionaries and merge them together. When I search for the solution, I can find ones that only work for dictionaries that only have common keys, or only have different keys, but not a solution to both.

Example of what I want below.

**Input**

```
x = {"a": 91, "b": 102}
y = {"b": 8, "c": True}
```

**Output**

```
z = {"a": 91, "b": 110, "c": True}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the values of dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `dictionary comprehension`, `dict.get` method and `set union between dict.key objects`:

```
>>> z = {k: x[k] + y[k]
            if (k in x and k in y)
            else x.get(k) or y.get(k)
            for k in sorted(x.keys() | y.keys())}
>>> z
{'a': 91, 'b': 110, 'c': 1}
```